# Binding to DataGridColumn with IMultiValueConverter encounters issues while using a similiar IValueConverter does not

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, imultivalueconverter

I have 2 Datagrid checkbox columns each with a binding.

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="DataGrid1" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource TableViewSource}}">
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Required" Width="50" MinWidth="50">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Binding>
                <Binding Path="Required" Converter="{StaticResource DateTimeToBooleanConverter}"/>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Required Test" Width="60" MinWidth="60">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DateTimeToBooleanMultiverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Required_Date" />
                    <Binding Path="Required_Time" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid>
```

The bindings simply write the date/time the box was checked to the db field `"Required"` and null when unchecked.

In the first checkbox everything works great with the following converter:

```
public class DateTimeToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{

public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == true) {
        return System.DateTime.Now.Date;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

In the last column I wanted to save the date and time into 2 different fields `"Required_Date"` and `"Required_Time" (String)`.  The following `IMultiConverter` was created to handle it:

```
public class DateTimeToBooleanMultiverter : IMultiValueConverter
{

public object Convert(object[] values, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values[0] != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public object[] ConvertBack(object value, System.Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value != null) {
        if (value == true) {
            return {
                System.DateTime.Now.Date,
                System.DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString()
            };
        }
    }
    return {
        null,
        null
    };
}
}
```

On initial load the column looks good.  The column has all the appropriate cell checked.  However, when the value is checked/unchecked I get the following binding error.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='True' MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'CellContent' (type 'String')
```

Further, when I uncheck a cell it doesn't uncheck properly and I notice through some breakpoints in my converter that values are coming in as `DependencyProperty.Unset` (Probably due to the binding warning).

### (9-30-12)

I found a more promising lead in a codeplex comment:

> "The reason that MultiBindings are not working is that
>   DataGridHelper.UpdateSource uses GetBindingExpression and not
>   GetBindingExpressionBase. If this is changed multi and priority
>   bindings should work."

I attempted to set updating to `Explicit` and create a `DataGrid_EndCellEdit` event that calls the `BindingBaseExpression` to update but I think the DataGridColumn is ignoring the update option.

### (10-12-12)

Still no luck, I tried working with `BindingBaseExpression` to no avail.  Obviously the `IMultiValueCOnverter` binding is doing something odd.