# Save Extra Infromation after editing DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` and others.  The `DataGrid ItemSource` is mapped to a `ObservableCollection` that contains rows of `Tasks`. The Task class includes properties like `"ID", "IsScheduled", "IsScheduled_Date", "IsScheduled_EditorID", Etc.`  I am trying to figure how to make the one `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` field (`IsScheduled`) also save the date (`IsScheduled_Date`) and who made the change (`IsScheduled_EditorID`) when checked.

(1) I have tried to make this save the extra data using multibinding, but my efforts have so far failed.  You can see follow my progress with solving a similar issue [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073597/).

(2) I have tried having the `DataGrid` `CellEditEnding` event save the extra data but it ended up committing the extra data before the IsScheduled data was committed and caused troubles whenever the row and/or cell edit was canceled.

(3) I have tried listening to the property change event in my Task class and assigning the additional changes there.  This seemed to work fine until I realized that when the data was first loaded it cause a change event that overwrote any earlier changes.

#### Added Information

---

The `Task` class is an `Entity Framework Class` that was generated from a DB. I was listening to the `OnIscheduledChanged` event and making the necessary changes because when I did it in the generated class it was always overwritten.

#### More Info

---

There seems to be some confusion about the Task class.  As I stated it is generated by the Entity Framework and a breakpoint shows the setters being called on load... Overwriting the change.  Not to mention any custom code being overwritten everytime the code regenerates.

> ```
>     /// <summary>
>     /// No Metadata Documentation available.
>     /// </summary>
>     [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
>     [DataMemberAttribute()]
>     public global::System.Boolean IsScheduled
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             return _IsScheduled;
>         }
>         set
>         {
>             OnIsScheduledChanging(value);
>             ReportPropertyChanging("IsScheduled");
>             _IsScheduled = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
>             ReportPropertyChanged("IsScheduled");
>             OnIsScheduledChanged();
>         }
>     }
>     private global::System.Boolean _IsScheduled;
>     partial void OnIsScheduledChanging(global::System.Boolean value);
>     partial void OnIsScheduledChanged();
> ```

Any Ideas?

Comment: If these properties are so interconnected, why is not this logic implemented inside IsScheduled property setter?

Comment: I think the 3d way is Ok. I'd rather look for the solution for correct initialization.

Comment: The properties weren't connected in the setter.  I was listening for the change event for IsScheduled in a partial class to the Task class (Which was generated by Entity Framework)

Comment: You can create some proxy wich will stand as a ViewModel for the Task class and what Blam offers you if I understand him correctly.
But that costs extra code. For this purpose you can use http://automapper.org/  By the way, some developers insist on not pushing pure data object to the View but creating DataTransferObjects.

Comment: I am not so sure about the proxy you are talking about and what I interpreted from his post was a standard class with property change notification held in a collection with collection change notification.  Which basically was my option (3).  The only difference being was in mine I received rows from the DB that call the setter right off the bat. Instead of `xxxs.Add(new xxx("Mike"));` It would be more like `xxx newxxx1("Mike"); newxxx1.isChecked = true; xxxs.Add(newxxx1);` with the framework making the call. (and calling the setter which overwrites the date etc.)

Comment: I meant `xxx newxxx1 = new xxx("Mike");` and not `xxx newxxx1("Mike");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a ViewModel class for the entity model that exposed the same property. I bound the DataGrid ItemSource to a list of the wrapped Task Models (e.g. below).  [Obviously this is quick example class to show the property and would need property notification to work properly]

```
Class TaskViewModel
{
    private Task task;
    public Boolean IsScheduled
    {
        get
        {
            return task.IsScheduled;
        }
        set
        {
            this.task.IsScheduled = value;
            this.task.IsScheduledDate = Date.Now();
        }

    TaskViewModel(Task task)
    {
       this.task = task;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the class

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<xxx> xxxs { get; private set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            xxxs = new ObservableCollection<xxx>();
            xxxs.Add(new xxx("Mike", false));
            xxxs.Add(new xxx("Sarah", true));

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class xxx: INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
                }
            }

            private bool isChecked;
            public bool IsChecked
            {
                get { return isChecked; }
                set
                {
                    if (isChecked == value) return;
                    if (value) FirstName = DateTime.Now.ToString(); else FirstName = string.Empty;
                    // update db
                    isChecked = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
                }
            }
            public string FirstName { get; private set; }
            public xxx(string firstName, bool _isChecked) { FirstName = firstName; isChecked = _isChecked; }
        }
    }

        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=xxxs}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="CheckBox" Binding="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text"  Binding="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: (I added some info above about the Task Class)  The Task class IsScheduled is called when getting the information from the database.  In Option (3) as I described above my Setter like your Setter will cause the values to be overwritten if IsChecked comes in from the DB as true.

Comment: Come on apply yourself.  Read the value from the DB and assign it in the constructor.

Comment: How can there be changes earlier than when the data was loaded?

Comment: I don't think it is constructive to degrade someones efforts.

Comment: Also, It is changing at load is the issue.